# Electrons in different shells

Tags: electrons, orbitals

I know this is a correct image, but I am a bit confused because I have seen different versions. If the 3rd orbital can take 18 electrons, why does it suddenly have 8 valence electrons on the 4th orbital, and then another electron on the 5th. I have seen other examples where the 4th orbital goes up to 32 electrons. How do I know when to use which ? I believe it might have to do with the complexity of the atom. Could someone please explain it in simpler terms

Couldn't attach the picture so I have the link here: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:37_rubidium_(Rb)_enhanced_Bohr_model.png

Comment: The diagonal principle can be used to memorize electronic configuration.

Comment: The name for the diagonal filling process is typically given as the Aufbau principle. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Atoms:_Aufbau_principle_and_Madelung_rule

Comment: I think images have to be jpg not png.

Comment: see http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18466/difference-between-shells-subshells-and-orbitals

Answer (score 0):

The electron configuration of an Rubidium atom can be written like this:
[image]
You are correct, the 4th Shell may hold a maximum of 32 electrons. However, electrons are arranged in a way so they have the least energy. As you can see above, the 4th shell is not completely filled because orbital 5s is a lower energy orbital, thus preferred over 4d. This principle applies to all atoms.

A easy method to remember is via the Aufbau principle:

[image]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_configuration#Atoms:_Aufbau_principle_and_Madelung_rule